# C# XSLT Transforming Large XML Files Quickly

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm transforming a > 2GB file with a lookup template in the XSLT.
I would like this to run faster but can't find any low hanging fruit to improve performance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm a newb when it comes to transformations.

This is the current format of the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <attribute>
            <name>text12</name>
            <value>B00085590</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>text34</name>
            <value>Atomos</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>date866</name>
            <value>02/21/1991</value>
        </attribute>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <attribute>
            <name>text12</name>
            <value>B00058478</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>text34</name>
            <value>Balderas</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>date866</name>
            <value>11/24/1997</value>
        </attribute>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

The xslt I used for the transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <!--Identify location of the lookup xml-->
    <xsl:param name="lookupDoc" select="document('C:\Projects\Attributes.xml')" />  

    <!--Main Template-->
    <xsl:template match="/contacts">        

            <!--Apply Formatted Contacts Template-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="contact" />            

    </xsl:template>

    <!--Formatted Contacts Template-->
    <xsl:template match="contact">
        <contact>
            <xsl:for-each select="attribute">
                <!--Create variable to hold New Name after passing the Data Name to the Lookup Template-->
                <xsl:variable name="newName">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$lookupDoc/attributes/attribute">
                        <xsl:with-param name="nameToMatch" select="name" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:variable>     
                <!--Format Contact Element with New Name variable-->
                <xsl:element name="{$newName}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:element>          
            </xsl:for-each>
        </contact>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Lookup Template-->
    <xsl:template match="attributes/attribute">
        <xsl:param name="nameToMatch" />            
            <xsl:value-of select='translate(translate(self::node()[name = $nameToMatch]/mappingname, "()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;&apos;&amp;,.?[]=-+/\:1234567890", "")," ","")' />
        </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample Lookup XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<attributes>
    <attribute>
        <name>text12</name>
        <mappingname>ID</mappingname>
        <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
        <size>30</size>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>text34</name>
        <mappingname>Last Name</mappingname>
        <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
        <size>30</size>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>date866</name>
        <mappingname>DOB</mappingname>
        <datatype>Date</datatype>
        <size></size>
    </attribute>
</attributes>
```

Transformed XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <ID>B00085590</ID>
        <LastName>Brady</LastName>
        <DOB>02/21/1991</DOB>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <ID>B00058478</ID>
        <LastName>Balderas</LastName>
        <DOB>11/24/1997</DOB>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

C#

```
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(true, true);
XslCompiledTransform ContactsXslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
ContactsXslt.Load(@"C:\Projects\ContactFormat.xslt", settings, new XmlUrlResolver());

using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Projects\Contacts.xml")){
   using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Projects\FormattedContacts.xml")) {
      w.WriteStartElement("contacts");
      while (r.Read()) {                        
         if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && r.Name == "contact") {
            XmlReader temp = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(r.ReadOuterXml()));                                
            ContactsXslt.Transform(temp, null, w);                            
         }
      }                        
   }
}
```

The approach I'm taking is transforming 1 node at a time to avoid an OutOfMemoryException. Should I be feeding larger chunks through to speed up the process? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: I wonder whether `XmlReader temp = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(r.ReadOuterXml()));` is necessary, can't you just pass the `XmlReader r` you have positioned on a `contact` element directly as the first argument to the `Transform` method? Or does `XslCompiledTransform` then close you the `XmlReader`? But even in that case I think doing `XmlReader temp = r.ReadSubtree()` is preferred and intended API use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify the XSLT code

```
       <xsl:for-each select="attribute">
            <!--Create variable to hold New Name after passing the Data Name to the Lookup Template-->
            <xsl:variable name="newName">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$lookupDoc/attributes/attribute">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nameToMatch" select="name" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:variable>
```

using the template

```
   <xsl:template match="attributes/attribute">
    <xsl:param name="nameToMatch" />            
        <xsl:value-of select='translate(translate(self::node()[name = $nameToMatch]/mappingname, "()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;&apos;&amp;,.?[]=-+/\:1234567890", "")," ","")' />
    </xsl:template>
```

to

```
       <xsl:for-each select="attribute">
            <!--Create variable to hold New Name after passing the Data Name to the Lookup Template-->
            <xsl:variable name="newName">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$lookupDoc/attributes/attribute[name = current()/name]"/>
            </xsl:variable>
```

with the template being simplified to

```
   <xsl:template match="attributes/attribute">
        <xsl:value-of select='translate(translate(mappingname, "()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;&apos;&amp;,.?[]=-+/\:1234567890", "")," ","")' />
    </xsl:template>
```

I think that for sure is a more concise and XSLT way of expressing the approach, whether it improves performance is something you would have to test.

In general with XSLT to improve performance of cross-references/lookups it is recommended to use a key so you would use

```
<xsl:key name="att-lookup" match="attributes/attribute" use="name"/>
```

and then use it as

```
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="name"/>
            <xsl:variable name="newName">
                <!-- in XSLT 1 we need to change the context doc for the key lookup -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc">
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('att-lookup', $name)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
```

I think that would considerable speed up the lookup in a single transformation, as you combine XmlReader and XSLT to run the XSLT many times on as many elements your XmlReader finds I can't tell whether it helps a lot, you would need to try.

As pointed out in the XSLT 3 suggestion, I would also consider transforming the lookup file first and once to avoid the repetition of all those `translate` calls to create proper XML element names. Either do that outside of the existing XSLT or do it inside by using a variable and then `exsl:node-set` to convert the result tree fragment into a variable. But in your case as you run the XSLT repeatedly I think it is probably better to first transform the lookup document outside of the main XSLT, to avoid having to do all those `translate`s again and again.

Comment: This worked great. The performance gained by using the key made the transformation time go from hours to under 5 minutes. I'll have to explore XSLT 3.0 in the future. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When reading huge xml files always use XmlReader.  I like using a combination of XmlReader and Xml linq.  I also like using dictionaries.  See code below :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "contact")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("contact");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement xContact = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    Contact newContact = new Contact();
                    Contact.contacts.Add(newContact);

                    newContact.attributes = xContact.Descendants("attribute")
                        .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("name"), y => (string)y.Element("value"))
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Contact
    {
        public static List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();

        public Dictionary<string, string> attributes { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might want to look into solving the task with XSLT 3 and its streaming feature (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#streaming-concepts) as there you could process the huge input file in a forwards only but declarative way where you only in the template for the `attribute` element you need to ensure you work with a intentionally created full copy of that element to allow XPath navigation to the child elements. Additionally I think it makese sense to read in the lookup document only once and do the `translate` calls to create the proper element names only once. So the following is a streaming XSLT 3 solution runnable with Saxon 9.8 EE which transforms the lookup document into an XPath 3.1 map (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps) and otherwise uses a streamable mode to process the large, main input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs map"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- could of course load the document using select="document('lookup.xml')" instead of inlining it as done here just for the example and testing -->
    <xsl:param name="lookup-doc">
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>text12</name>
                <mappingname>ID</mappingname>
                <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
                <size>30</size>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <name>text34</name>
                <mappingname>Last Name</mappingname>
                <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
                <size>30</size>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <name>date866</name>
                <mappingname>DOB</mappingname>
                <datatype>Date</datatype>
                <size></size>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>      
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable 
        name="lookup-map"
        as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
        select="map:merge(
        $lookup-doc/attributes/attribute 
        ! 
        map { 
        string(name) : translate(translate(mappingname, '()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;''&amp;,.?[]=-+/\:1234567890', ''), ' ','')
        }
        )"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="contact/attribute">
        <xsl:variable name="attribute-copy" select="copy-of()"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$lookup-map($attribute-copy/name)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$attribute-copy/value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample (there running with Saxon 9.8 HE which ignores the streaming and does normal XSLT processing) is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Ct/1.

To run streaming XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.8 and C# you use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Xslt30Transformer.html and set up `ApplyTemplates` on an input `Stream` with your huge input XML (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Xslt30Transformer.html#ApplyTemplates(System.IO.Stream,Saxon.Api.XmlDestination)).